# Remove whitespace below flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to design a landing page where different sections have different background-colors. The first section container (brown background) is a Flexbox to position the child elements. Below the first section comes another container (blue background) that also spans the whole width of the page.

**Problem:** There is some whitespace between the two containers, that I can't remove.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.about-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 490px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #605B56;
}

#title {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #8EB8E5;
}

.pic {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8EB8E5;
}

p {
  text-align: right;
  color: $white;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.section-container {
  background: #8EB8E5;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-container">
  <div class="about-text">
    <h3 id="title">Title</h3>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pic"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-container">
  <h3>
    Section Title
  </h3>
  Some text for the next section
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z4oecan1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<h3>` elements have a default margin; remove it. use padding on the `<h3>` instead if you need to push it down.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.about-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 490px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #605B56;
}

#title {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #8EB8E5;
}

.pic {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8EB8E5;
}

p {
  text-align: right;
  color: $white;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.section-container {
  background: #8EB8E5;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-container">
  <div class="about-text">
    <h3 id="title">Title</h3>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pic"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-container">
  <h3>
    Section Title
  </h3>
  Some text for the next section
</div>
```

Another option is to leave the margins as-is and add `overflow:auto` to the `section-container` div to fix the collapsed margins.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.about-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 490px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #605B56;
}

#title {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #8EB8E5;
}

.pic {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8EB8E5;
}

p {
  text-align: right;
  color: $white;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.section-container {
  background: #8EB8E5;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-container">
  <div class="about-text">
    <h3 id="title">Title</h3>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pic"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-container">
  <h3>
    Section Title
  </h3>
  Some text for the next section
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the rookie mistake :|

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the default margin-top of the `h3` in the second section, which exceeds its container (collapsing margins....)

To avoid that, set `margin-top: 0` for that `h3`, and to recreate the space above it, add a `padding-top` to it.

https://jsfiddle.net/031p3m04/1/